# How to parametrize with pytest over a cartesian product of parameters, some fixtured?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm writing tests for a base class and its subclasses.
It looks roughly like this:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def bc()
    return BaseClass(...)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('param1,param2', [...])
def test_baseclass_func1(bc, param1, param2):
    assert ...

@pytest.mark.parametrize('param1,param2', [...])
def test_baseclass_func2(bc, param1, param2):
    assert ...

@pytest.mark.parametrize('param1,param2', [xyz])
def test_baseclass_func3(bc, param1, param2):
    assert ...

@pytest.mark.parametrize('param1,param2', [xyz])
def test_subclass1_func3(param1, param2):
    sc1 = SubClass1(...)
    assert ...

@pytest.mark.parametrize('param1,param2', [xyz])
def test_subclass2_func3(param1, param2):
    sc1 = SubClass2(...)
    assert ...
```

So I wish to use the fixtured BaseClass instance, I have no apparent reason to use fixture over the subclasses, and I wish to avoid the 3 times copy-paste of the test for func3.
My best shot is to use one more parametrization:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('classtype', [
        (BaseClass,),
        (SubClass1,),
        (SubClass2,),
])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('param1,param2', [xyz])
def test_func3(classtype, param1, param2):
    class_inst = classtype()
    assert ...
```

but since it requires an extra instance of BaseClass, I guess there's a better solution. What trick am I missing?

Comment: So you want to use `BaseClass` instance from `bc` if `classtype == BaseClass` and create instance of `Subclass*` if `classtype != BaseClass`, right?

Comment: That's right. If I could access bc manually (and not just as an argument to test_* functions), I could solve it with parametrization as above and an if condition.

Comment: Maybe you need just a global variable `BC = BaseClass()` instead of fixture `bc`?

Comment: Actually, it could work in this case. To be honest, even creating two instances, in this case won't be too awful.
But this is a typical situation where sometimes a fixture is preferred (i.e. for a teardown cleaning), and it seems strange to me that there's no inherent solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could use the [indirect parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#deferring-the-setup-of-parametrized-resources) to transform class arguments to instances passed to the test:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def instance(request):
    cls = request.param
    instance = cls()
    yield instance
    # cleanup instance here if necessary

@pytest.mark.parametrize('instance', (BaseClass, SubClass1, SubClass2,), indirect=True)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('param1,param2', (('spam', 'foo'), ('eggs', 'bar')))
def test_func3(instance, param1, param2):
    assert instance.func3(param1, param2) == 'bacon'
```

Since the `instance` fixture is session-scoped, all created instances are created once and reused throughout the test session. Should you need a more sophisticated instance creation, you can do it in the fixture, keeping the tests clean. Example with reusing the `bc` fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def bc():
    return BaseClass(...)

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def instance(request, bc):
    cls = request.param
    if cls.__name__ == 'BaseClass':
        instance = bc
    else:
        instance = cls()
    yield instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are interested in such a fixture that will not create `BaseClass` instance until it is not called:

```
@pytest.fixture
def callable_bc():
    def _bc():
        return BaseClass(...)
    return _bc

@pytest.mark.parametrize('classtype', [
        (BaseClass,),
        (SubClass1,),
        (SubClass2,),
])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('param1,param2', [xyz])
def test_func3(classtype, param1, param2, callable_bc):
    class_inst = classtype() if classtype != BaseClass else callable_bc()
    assert ...
```